# C# get cpu usage for certain process?

Tags: c#, windows, process, taskmanager

in taskmanager process tab ,I can see a lot of processes and it's pid ,cpu usage 
[image]

I want to get a process's cpuusage,may be a process have multi-pids,so  I wish it can list all this pids cpuusage?

for example in this picture,I want to list process conhost.exe cpu usage,
it has 8 pids,so I hope it can list 8 cpu usages

How to write this code using C#?

And is there have some cmd command to list process,pid,cpu usage??

Comment: For listing processes you can use [tasklist](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html)

Comment: @Nameismy I want to list pid and cpu usage ,how to use "tasklist" commnad

Comment: @Luaan please give me the link

Comment: It's right there on top of your answer (under `This question already has an answer here:`).